# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5. update database

Tags: java, error-handling, sql-update, sqlexception

I have this error code in the dialog box: `java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5` when i try to update my JTable/JTextFields into my SQL database.

I have checked similar questions on the site, but non seem to have the solution to my problem. I have checked the database, i have checked my connection code, the update code and can't find where this extra parameter making the problem should be? Please help a new beginner!

So now i understand that the problem is at `WHERE id=?` as i suspected, but my id only exist as a row count/main key in my SQL DB, so it is going to be different depending on which row you choose/click on, so i can't set a specific value beforehand at the `pst.setInt(5, ? )`. What to insert instead then - so i dont lose the automatic row count on my clients list in the JTable?

```
//This method contains all codes for database connection.
    private void upDateDB() {
    try { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/num klienter", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM klient");
        
    ResultSet rs =pst.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData StData = rs.getMetaData();
        
    q = StData.getColumnCount();
        
    DefaultTableModel RecordTable = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    RecordTable.setRowCount(0);
        
    while(rs.next()){
       Vector<String> columnData = new Vector<String>();
            
    for (i = 1; i <= q; i++) {
       columnData.add(rs.getString("id"));
       columnData.add(rs.getString("Name"));
       columnData.add(rs.getString("Birthday"));
       columnData.add(rs.getString("Description"));
       columnData.add(rs.getString("Other"));
}
       RecordTable.addRow(columnData);                
            
 }} catch (Exception ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}}

updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) { 
            
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/num klienter", "root", "");    
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE klient SET Name=?,Birthday=?,Description=?,Other=? WHERE id=?");
            table.getSelectedRow();
        
            pst.setString(1, nameTxt.getText()); 
            pst.setString(2, dayTxt.getText()+"-" + monthTxt.getText()+"-" + yearTxt.getText());
            pst.setString(3, descriptionTxt.getText());
            pst.setString(4, otherTxt.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated in database");
            upDateDB();
            
        }catch (Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex); 
}
```

Comment: You have 5 `?` in your update sql statement but only set 4 parameters.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS i did already try before this question was posted, to remove the ? mark after the WHERE id=" But then i just get another error not allowing me to do that. Should i remove the = sign also for it to work then? i cant remember if i already tried that actually.

Comment: I remember now that it updates all the rows to be the same, if i remove both =?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to insert the 5th `pst.` statement for the `id=?` like this:

```
pst.setInt(5,table.getRowCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`

this can just be removed. It hasn't been neccessary for 20 years.

> `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/num klienter", "root", "");`

This is a memory leak; the connection is opened, and will remain open forever; your SQL server won't allow more than a handful of open connections, so pretty soon your MySQL server will be unreachable by any service (including this java code) until you kill the java app which closes the connections. Use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for *all* resources you create.

> `PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM klient");`

This is also a resource and needs try-with-resources.

> `ResultSet rs =pst.executeQuery();`

You guessed it. Try-with-resources a third time. If you find the code becoming unwieldy, JDBC is very low level and not all that great for 'end user' coding. Use a nice abstraction like [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/) or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org).

> `columnData.add(rs.getString("Fødselsdag"));`

non-ASCII in your column names? That's never going to go well. I strongly suggest you don't do it this way.

> `q = StData.getColumnCount();`

> `for (i = 1; i <= q; i++) {`

This is bizarre. q holds the **column count** - that's the number of columns in your query. And then you hardcode the 5 column names, so q is always 5. Then, you add all 5 values (id, Navn, Fødselsdag, etc), and then do that 5 times, for a total of 25 runs, and your data repeated 5 times. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish by asking for the known information (get the column count from the metadata, which you already know).

> `PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE klient SET Navn=?,Fødselsdag=?,Beskrivelse=?,Andet=? WHERE id=?");`

I count 5 `?`, but only 4 `pst.setString` statements. You forgot `pst.setInt(5, theValue)`.

The update code gets all the same caveats about try-with-resources.

> `pst.setString(2, dayTxt.getText()+"-" + monthTxt.getText()+"-" + yearTxt.getText());`

Not how you do date stuff with DBs. There is a `pst.setDate`, but optimally you should use `pst.setObject`, passing an instance of `java.time.LocalDate`. Whether MySQL actually supports that - not sure, you'd have to check.

Comment: that was a really adequate answer you brought me here. Im not sure if i understand all of it because i am NEW with big letters at coding. I toke a main course for the most important/basic stuff for java coding and the rest i have watched Youtube tutorials for how to do things - that might explain why some of my code is outdated.

Comment: Also the reason why i did my "date stuff" like that was because i could not make my JDate/calender work with some different types of code. So i made it like i did to make the DB work at first and then later on i will try to find "the real" way of handeling birthdate information instead of using JTextFields.

Comment: The "id" (this only exist as a row count/main key in DB) is going to be different depending on which row you choose/click on, so i can't set a specific value beforehand at the pst.setInt(5, ). What to insert instead then?

Comment: The DB engine has no idea what row you want to update if you don't specify an ID. If you want to _update_ an _existing_ row, you just can't do that without knowing something that uniquely identifies that row, so, arrange it so that you DO know what the id is. If on the other hand you want to insert an entirely new row in your DB, you don't use UPDATE at all. You'd write `INSERT INTO klient (name, birthday, description, other) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`, set your 4 options with `pst.setX(...)`, and execute it. Assuming your DB is set up correctly, that'll work, and generates an id automatically.

Comment: Both my insert (add) and delete function as they should without errors or problems. But the struggle is with the update of the chosen existing row. But how do i make it find the automatic id number on the clicked row to execute the update?

Comment: It's the 'id' field of the column. Store that someplace associated with the row in your GUI.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the solution finally dropped down on me!